# Redirect Loops and .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just moved from a CentOS dedi to an Ubuntu VPS. The site is custom coded PHP.

Frontend works fine (including rewrite rules). The admin backend I can't get rewrite rules to work...

First error:

```
H00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Then after using debug level:

```
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /admin/index.php
```

The relevant bits of my htaccess are:

```
# mod_rewrite set:

Options +Includes

RewriteEngine on

# Administration
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/+)admin/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/index.php [L,QSA]

# Rewrite orther
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)index.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)syscmd.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# If Rewriting Failure, Show error message (Internal backup)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/+)syscmd.php$
RewriteRule (.*) \1 [F]
```

This was working fine on CentOS too.

Any ideas? I already tried adding the following as the first condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/ [NC]
```

That stopped it rewriting /admin completely.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules don't appear correct as `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` represents filesystem path and it shouldn't be used in target URLs.

Try these rules:

```
Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Administration
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php [L,NC]

# Rewrite other
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/syscmd\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! The first part under #Administration worked and I was able to access the /admin area fine. But the changes under "#Rewrite other" broke the frontend. Basically I could load the homepage using /index.php and all other inner pages worked, however if I tried to load the homepage without index.php (ie www.domain.com) then it would come up with a 403 forbidden error, so I just reverted that section to what I had originally. Of course happy to try any other changes you might think should work. Thanks again!